# Independence between magnitude and sign

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with symmetric distribution around zero, prove that the random variables $|X|$ and $Y$ are independent, in which $Y = 1$ if $X > 0$, and $Y = 0$ if $X \leq 0$.

I would like to know if my proof is correct.

We know that $P(|X| \leq x \cap Y = y) = P(|X| \leq x | Y = y) \cdot P(Y = y)$. In order to show that $|X|$ and $Y$ are independent, we must show that $P(|X| \leq x | Y = y) = P(|X| \leq x) $.

Consider $Y = 1$. Then $X > 0 \implies X = |X|$. Thus $P(|X| \leq x | Y = 1) = P(|X| \leq x) = P(X \leq x)$.

Now consider $Y = 0$. Then we have $X < 0 \implies X = -|X|$. Thus $P(|X| \leq x | Y = 0) = P(X \geq -x) = P(X \leq x)$, from the symmetry hypothesis.

It thus follows that $P(|X| \leq x \cap Y = y) = P(|X| \leq x) \cdot P(Y = y)$.

I think the proof is correct, however my professor has told me that it is wrong. If someone could explain the reason I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that what you want to show is that $\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x|Y=y)=\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x)$. But you use this twice in your argument. You can't use the thing you're trying to prove in the proof.

Your proof also asserts that $\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x)=\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant x)$, which need not be true, and is not the conclusion you want. In fact, there are definitely some $x$ for which this inequality does not hold. For example, $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x)=0$ while $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant x)=1/2$.

Since $X$ is continuous, $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=0$. By symmetry, $\mathbb{P}(Y=1)=\mathbb{P}(X>0)=1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=\mathbb{P}(X<0)=1/2$. For $x\leqslant 0$, $\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x)=0$, so $$\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x) \cap (Y=y))=0=\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$$ for any value of $y$. So we only need to be concerned with $x>0$. Also, for $y\notin \{0,1\}$, $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=0$, so $\mathbb{P}((|X|\leqslant x)\cap (Y=y))=0=\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$. So we only need to be concerned with $y\in \{0,1\}$.

We calculate

We can say \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}((|X|\leqslant x)\cap (Y=1)) & = \mathbb{P}((|X|\leqslant x) \cap (X>0)) = \mathbb{P}(0<X\leqslant x) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(-x\leqslant X\leqslant x) \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x) = \mathbb{P}(Y=1)\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant x).\end{align*}

The argument for $y=0$ is similar.

Comment: Very illuminating. Thank you so much!